# Rails Shopping Cart - not adding to current order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, e-commerce, cart

Rails noob here.

I'm building a basic shopping cart and it was working perfectly before. Without changing any code (I git reset --hard to my prev commit where it was working) it broke. (?!?) Here's the breakdown:

Github Repo: https://github.com/christinecha/michaka

- Creates a product. ✓
- Adds Product ID to a new Order Item. ✓
- Adds Order Item to an Order. ✓

--

Possible Issues

! - New Orders keep being created as you create Order Items = cart is always empty.

! - Cart is not connecting to the right Order ID

! - New sessions are being triggered = new Orders = problem

--

ORDER ITEMS CONTROLLER

```
    class OrderItemsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @order = current_order
    @order_item = @order.order_items.new(order_item_params)
    @order.save
    session[:order_id] = @order.id
  end

  def update
    @order = current_order
    @order_item = @order.order_items.find(params[:id])
    @order_item.update_attributes(order_item_params)
    @order_items = @order.order_items
  end

  def destroy
    @order = current_order
    @order_item = @order.order_items.find(params[:id])
    @order_item.destroy
    @order_items = @order.order_items
  end
private
  def order_item_params
    params.require(:order_item).permit(:quantity, :product_id)
  end
end
```

SESSION_STORE.RB

```
Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_bead-project_session'
```

ORDER MODEL

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :order_status
  has_many :order_items
  before_create :set_order_status
  before_save :update_subtotal

  def subtotal
    order_items.collect { |oi| oi.valid? ? (oi.quantity * oi.unit_price) : 0 }.sum
  end

  def subtotal_cents
    subtotal * 100
  end


private
  def set_order_status
    self.order_status_id = 1
  end

  def update_subtotal
    self[:subtotal] = subtotal
  end

end
```

APPLICATION CONTROLLER

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  helper_method :current_order

  def current_order
    if !session[:order_id].nil?
      Order.find(session[:order_id])
    else
      Order.new
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Did you try to debug? `OrderItemsController#create` - `session[:order_id] = @order.id` is it work ? What value is on `session[:order_id]` in `application_controller#current_order`?

Comment: Maybe something with your browser?

Comment: @denys281 doesn't seem like a browser issue, unfortunately. The value on session[:order_id] is current_order.id (see OrderItems Controller)

Comment: Did you debug current_order method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like ProductsController#create is called twice, once with format html and once as json.

I think you're submitting some of your data via ajax but still doing a post request from the form.  However your controller, in it's `format.html` response is redirecting before all of the javascript actions have completed.

Since you only save @order and set the session from OrderItemsController#create which is called by js after your initial ajax().success, it is incomplete when the redirect is received.

What I think happens on click:

1. ajax post request AND regular form post
2. ajax success -> submit #order_item_product_id form
3. redirected by original form post response

I would suggest either redesigning the submit process to submit through regular form post or entirely through js.  For example you could disable post from the form and change OrderItemsController#create to finally redirect (via js) `render :js => "window.location.href = '/cart';"`

Comment: Happy to help, and more often than not I learn something along the way :-)