# Rails shopping cart - order not instantiated when trying to add products to cart (nil value)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, e-commerce, cart

I'm trying to build a rails (with devise gem) e-shop app with a basic shopping cart.  I've found some tutorials over the internet to handle the cart and I've followed it.
The code is very similar to the below post:

> [Rails Shopping Cart - not adding to current order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32464758/rails-shopping-cart-not-adding-to-current-order)

However, I have an issue with the order part when trying to add a product to the cart.  the order is never instantiated (i assume) and therefore can't be saved and products are not added to the cart.
I've made a lot of research and tried to debugg but I'm stuck.

Sorry for the long post but I'm trying to be as precise as possible, in order to ease the answers.

Can you help find out where am I wrong?
Thx in advance for your answers.

---

Controllers:

**Order_items**

```
class OrderItemsController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :authenticate_user!

  def create
    @order = current_order
    @item = @order.order_items.new(order_item_params)
    if @order.save
      session[:order_id] = @order.id
      flash[:notice] = "Product Successfully added to your cart"
      redirect_to produits_path
    else
      flash[:notice] = "Problem"
      redirect_to produits_path
    end
  end

  def update
    @order = current_order
    @order_item = @order.order_items.find(params[:id])
    @order_item.update_attributes(order_item_params)
    @order_items = @order.order_items
  end

  def destroy
    @order = current_order
    @order_item = @order.order_items.find(params[:id])
    @order_item.destroy
    @order_items = @order.order_items
  end

private

  def order_item_params
    params.require(:order_item).permit(:quantity, :produit_id)
  end

end
```

**Carts**

```
class CartsController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :authenticate_user!

  def show
    @order_items = current_order.order_items
  end
end
```

**products**

```
class ProduitsController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :authenticate_user!

  def index
    @produits = Produit.all
    @order_item = current_order.order_items.new
  end
end
```

**application**

```
 class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  helper_method :current_order

  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  def current_order
    if !session[:order_id].nil?
      Order.find(session[:order_id])
    else
      Order.new
    end
  end

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    # For additional fields in app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:prenom, :nom, :adresse, :telephone])
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: [:prenom, :nom, :adresse, :telephone])
  end
end
```

Models:

**orderItem**

```
class OrderItem < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :order
  belongs_to :produit

  validates :quantity, presence: true, numericality: { only_integer: true, greater_than: 0 }
  validate :product_present
  validate :order_present

  before_save :finalize

  def unit_price
    if persisted?
      self[:unit_price]
    else
      produit.prix
    end
  end

  def total_price
    unit_price * quantity
  end

private

  def product_present
    if produit.nil?
      errors.add(:produit, "is not valid or is not active.")
    end
  end

  def order_present
    if order.nil?
      errors.add(:order, "is not a valid order.")
    end
  end

  def finalize
    self[:unit_price] = unit_price
    self[:total_price] = quantity * self[:unit_price]
  end
end
```

**order**

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :order_status
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :order_items
  before_create :set_order_status
  before_save :update_subtotal

  def subtotal
    order_items.collect { |oi| oi.valid? ? (oi.quantity * oi.prix) : 0 }.sum
  end


private
  def set_order_status
    self.order_status_id = 1
  end

  def update_subtotal
    self[:subtotal] = subtotal
  end
end
```

---

When debugging I see that I got the item variable ok (product id and quantity present) but order still "nil" so I enter in the else part of the code.

```
     4: def create
     5:   binding.pry
     6:   @order = current_order
     7:   @item = @order.order_items.new(order_item_params)
 =>  8:   if @order.save
     9:     session[:order_id] = @order.id
    10:     flash[:notice] = "Product Successfully added to your cart"
    11:     redirect_to produits_path
    12:   else
    13:     flash[:notice] = "Problem"
    14:     redirect_to produits_path
    15:   end
    16: end

[4] pry(#<OrderItemsController>)> @order
=> #<Order:0x00007f8714ed1a50
 id: nil,
 status: nil,
 total_price: nil,
 created_at: nil,
 updated_at: nil,
 subtotal: nil,
 shipping: nil,
 user_id: nil>
[5] pry(#<OrderItemsController>)> @item
=> #<OrderItem:0x00007f8718e684e8 id: nil, produit_id: 47, order_id: nil, quantity: 1, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>


     4: def create
     5:   binding.pry
     6:   @order = current_order
     7:   @item = @order.order_items.new(order_item_params)
     8:   if @order.save
     9:     session[:order_id] = @order.id
    10:     flash[:notice] = "Product Successfully added to your cart"
    11:     redirect_to produits_path
    12:   else
 => 13:     flash[:notice] = "Problem"
    14:     redirect_to produits_path
    15:   end
    16: end


pry(#<OrderItemsController>)> @order.save
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
  ↳ (pry):7
   (0.3ms)  ROLLBACK
  ↳ (pry):7
=> false
```

Comment: `update`  error was in the callbabk syntax in `Order` model  `before_validation :set_order_status, on: :create` sets the order status correctly.  I also remove the link with user which is unnecessary as i do not want a visitor to be connected to create a cart

Answer (score 0):

In the `pry` session try:

`@order.errors`

to see what validations are failing and thus stopping the `@order` from being saved.

Comment: Thanks for this tip.  I actually had an issue with a user_id that was required. this is solve but now issue is on the order_status that is not set.  I'll investigate around here